# Is there any way to trigger upstream jobs with parameters?

Tags: jenkins

I didn't find any solution to do this. Is there any plugins available to trigger upstream Jobs with parameters?

Answer (score 1):

**[Parameterized trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)** ,lets you trigger new builds when your build has completed, with various ways of specifying parameters for the new build.
You can add multiple configurations: each has a list of projects to trigger, a condition for when to trigger them (based on the result of the current build), and a parameters section.

There is also a ﻿Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin in case you want to trigger a build on a different/remote Jenkins Master.

The parameters section can contain a combination of one or more of the following:

- a set of predefined properties
- properties from a properties file read from the workspace of the
  triggering build
- the parameters of the current build
- Subversion revision: makes sure the triggered projects are built with
  the same revision(s) of the triggering build. You still have to make
  sure those projects are actually configured to checkout the right
  Subversion URLs.
- Restrict matrix execution to a subset: allows you to specify the same
  combination filter expression as you use in the matrix project
  configuration and further restricts the subset of the downstream
  matrix builds to be run.

The parameter section is itself pluggable, and other plugins can contribute other sources of parameters.

This triggering mechanism can be used both as a post-build step or as a build step, in which case you can also block for the completion of the triggered builds. This lets you create a "function call" like semantics.

Comment: This plugin is not supported to trigger a build flow or multijob in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Build Flow Plugin][1]

[1]: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin ""

Comment: But this plugin only supports downstream jobs

Comment: Can you please be more specific about "upstream"?

Comment: I'm using Multijob configuration. I can use build flow plugin to build downstrean jobs. If I used Multijob with parameters , this plugin doesn't support